# How filter latest m2m objects with a QuerySet in Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following model:

```
class Customer(SomeInheritedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

class Account(SomeInheritedModel):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='accounts')
    ...

class Product(SomeInheritedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

class License(SomeInheritedModel):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    maintenance = models.ManyToManyField('Maintenance', related_name="maintenances")

class Maintenance(SomeInheritedModel):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Once a license maintenance is renewed, a new `Maintenance` object is created. This way I can track back to all `Maintenance` a particular `License` has had.

Now I want to generate a report to show me all `Customers` which `License` are about to expire - based on their `Maintenance` expiry date. And I want only the **latest** `Maintenance` object a `License` has, because it is the latest sold. I don't want the others.

I know I could achieve this with a QuerySet and a for loop, but that would be a bit costy to the server, given a have a lot of entries.

Is there a way to do this filtering through a QuerySet? Something like this:

`Customer.objects.filter(accounts__licenses__maintenances__expiry_date__last__range=(now().date(), one_month_into_future().date()))`

I know I can use `__last` in some ocasions, but that doesn't quite work if I have to specify something after that.

#### Edit

I found my answer through what @hynekcer suggested. You can use `annotate`.

```
License.objects.filter(foo=True)
    .annotate(max_exp_date=models.Max('maintenances__expiration_date'))\
    .filter(max_exp_date__gte=report.start_date, max_exp_date__lte=report.end_date)\
    .select_related('account__customer')
```

Comment: Yes, you simplified it very nice. I thought that my answer was necessary for some older Django, but i see now that your solution works even on Django 1.2. :-)

Comment: @hynekcer Ohh ok. I am using Django 1.10.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **tl;dr )**

**The current important answer is the EDIT at the end.**

Yes, it is important to ignore all older related objects (maintenances), even those which are still valid, because there may exist a renewed maintenance.

I think that you simplified your real model so much, that it doesn't work good.
You have two chained ManyToMany relations with anonymous (not explicit) relationship table. This makes impossible to write right query sets.

**Bugs:**

1) You use the same name ("licenses" and also "maintenances") for a field and its `related_name`. It is a nonsense because: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

> **`related_name`**
>   The name to use for the relation from the related object back to this one. It’s also the default value for related_query_name (the name to use for the reverse filter name from the target model).

It is not useful that you will see a reverse queryset `maintenances` on object `Maintenance` to License. Similarly a queryset `licenses' on License to Customer. You can easily rename the related_name because it does't change the database and doesn't cause a migration.

2) Is the `License` a common or individual object? If it is individual then it doesn't need `many-to-many` relationship to Customer object. If it is common then you can't track a paid maintenance to individual customers through it. (You also don't mean that two customers are co-owners of one license! Are they? :-) You probably mean a common `LicensedProduct` and an individual `License` that connects the customer with that product. I understand that the user can buy one maintenace for more licenses and and many-to-many is here good.

First I fix the **model** (some way I guess before I can ask you)

```
class Customer(SomeInheritedModel):
    # "licenses" is the reverse query to License
    # optionally you can enable many-to-many relation to licensed products
    # lic_products = models.ManyToManyField(

class Product(models.Model):
    pass  # licensed product details

class License(SomeInheritedModel):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='licenses')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='+')  # used '+' because not deeded
    maintenances = models.ManyToManyField(
        Maintenance,
        through='LicenseMaintenance',
        through_fields=('license', 'maintenance'),
        related_name='licenses')

class Maintenance(SomeInheritedModel):
    start_date = DateTimeField(null=True)
    expiration_date = DateTimeField(null=True)

class LicenseMaintenance(models.Model):
    license = models.ForeignKey(License, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    maintenance = models.ForeignKey(Maintenance, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**querysets**: (can be simplified much by removing order_by and related fields)

```
remind_start = datetime.datetime.now(tz=TIMEZONE)
remind_end = remind_start + datetime.timedelta(days=30)

expiring_lic_maintenances = (
    LicenseMaintenance.objects.values('license',
                                      'license__customer',
                                      'license__customer__name')
    .annotate(max_exp_date=models.Max('maintenance__expiration_date'))
    .filter(max_exp_date__lte=remind_start, max_exp_date__gte=remind_end)
    .order_by('license__customer__name', 'license__customer', 'license')
)   # some small detail can be used like e.g. customer name in the example, not used later

expiring_licenses = (
    License.objects.filter(
        license__in=expiring_lic_maintenances.values_list('license', flat=True))
    .select_related('customer', 'product')
    .order_by('license__customer__name', 'license__customer', 'license')
)   # that queryset with subquery is executed by one SQL command
```

Not more than two SQL requests are executed by running these querysets:

```
# but I prefer a simple map and queryset with subquery:
expiration_map = {x.license_id: x.max_exp_date for x in expiring_lic_maintenances}


for lic in expiring_licenses:
    print("{name}, your maintenance for {lic_name} is expiring on {exp_date}".format(
        name=lic.customer.name,
        lic_name=lic.product.name,
        exp_date=expiration_map[lic.id],
    ))
```

I expect, that it is a new project and you don't need migrations yet for modified models. I wrote similar code so many times enough that I didn't verified it now. A mistake could happen and you can inform me sufficient time before the end of bounty easily.

---

**EDIT after edited question:**
Aggregation functions work correctly on many-to-many fields without explicit model for join table  in the current Django version:

```
>>> expiring = (
...     License.objects.values('id',
...                            'account__customer',
...                            'account__customer__name')
...     .annotate(max_exp_date=models.Max('maintenance__expiration_date'))
...     .filter(max_exp_date__gte=remind_start, max_exp_date__lte=remind_end)
... )
```

and look at **compiled SQL**:

```
>>> str(expiring.query)
SELECT app_license.id, app_account.customer_id, app_customer.name, MAX(app_maintenance.expiration_date) AS max_exp_date
    FROM app_license INNER JOIN app_account ON (app_license.account_id = app_account.id)
    INNER JOIN app_customer ON (app_account.customer_id = app_customer.id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN app_license_maintenance ON (app_license.id = app_license_maintenance.license_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN app_maintenance ON (app_license_maintenance.maintenance_id = app_maintenance.id)
    GROUP BY app_license.id, app_account.customer_id, app_customer.name
    HAVING (MAX(app_maintenance.expiration_date) >= 2017-04-07T13:45:35.485755 AND
            MAX(app_maintenance.expiration_date) <= 2017-03-08T13:45:35.485755
            )
```

In generally this is compiled by two outer joins.

---

**If you find a more complicated case**, where it doesn't work or the query is slow because it is more complicated for some database engines to optimize with outer joins, you can everytimes get the implicit model and run the query on it because it is the top model in the relation hierarchy:

we can **explore the implicit intermediate model** of the table:

```
>>> License.maintenance.through
app.models.License_maintenance
>>> LicenseMaintenance = License.maintenance.through
>>> LicenseMaintenance._meta.fields
(<django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: license>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: maintenance>)
```

and **use it**:  (all joins are automatically compiled to inner joins)

```
>>> expiring = (
...     LicenseMaintenance.objects.values('license',
...                                       'license__account__customer',
...                                       'license__account__customer__name')
...     .annotate(max_exp_date=models.Max('maintenance__expiration_date'))
...     .filter(max_exp_date__lte=remind_start, max_exp_date__gte=remind_end)
... )
```

Comment: You are right. The model I described here was a bad representation of my actual model. I have edited to something more close of what I have now. I was just hopping to get ideas of how to approach the query issue I am facing. `.annotate(max_exp_date=models.Max('maintenance__expiration_date'))` this called my attention and I think it will solve my problem. Can't I run this on Maintenance table? And yes, this is in Production already.

Comment: @Ev.: You can't run Max on Maintenance and group it by License if you wouldn't know the Model for join table between them. You must run it on LicenseMaintenance that you can find eventually by introspection if you don't create an explicit. See the edited answer.

Comment: I ran from License to Maintenance, using `annotate` and Max in `maintenances__expiry_date` and it seems to be working. I have ran tests and the output seems reasonable. :)

Comment: Yes, I tried it and edited the answer again with an example of correctly compiled query. Thank you for news, that it works easily in the current Django.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you have 2 options:
First is to use prefetch_related:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

now = timezone.now()
maintenance_qs = Maintenance.objects.filter(expiry_date__lte=now).order_by('-expire_date')
license_qs = License.objects.filter(maintenances__expiry_date__lte=now).\
    prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('maintenances', queryset=maintenance_qs)
    ).order_by(-'maintenances__expiry_date')
customers = Customer.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('licenses', queryset=license_qs))
```

It will hit database 3 times, you can read more about [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) and [Prefetch object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects). It will return all licenses and all maintenance but it will be sorted and you can take only 1 item. You can use it like this.

```
for customer in customers:
    last_license = customer.licenses.all()[0]
    last_maintenance = last_license.maintenances.all()[0]
```

Or you can try to use raw SQL. Your query look like:

```
customers = Customer.objects.raw(
'''
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT "yourapp_customer"."id", 
           "yourapp_license"."id", 
           "yourapp_maintenance"."id",
           "yourapp_maintanance"."start_date",
           "yourapp_maintanance"."expiration_date",
           MAX("yourapp_maintanance"."expiration_date") over (partition by "yourapp_customer"."id") as last_expired
    FROM "yourapp_customer"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "yourapp_customer_licenses" ON
        "yourapp_customer"."id" = "yourapp_customer_licenses"."customer_id"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "yourapp_license" ON
        "yourapp_license"."id" = "yourapp_customer_licenses"."license_id"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "yourapp_license_maintenances" ON
        "yourapp_license"."id" = "yourapp_license_maintenances"."license_id"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "yourapp_maintanance" ON
        "yourapp_maintanance"."id" = "yourapp_license_maintenances"."maintanance_id"
    WHERE "yourapp_maintanance"."expiration_date" < NOW()
) AS T
where expiration_date = last_expired
'''
)
```

It should work much faster, but using this query you can't construct License and Maintenance objects. All properties will be stored in Customer model. You can read more about [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-window.html)

Comment: The most important thing for me is to get the licenses based on their last maintenance object. If I can build up that list the rest should be easier. What I don't what is to have licenses appearing based on previous maintenance objects, because they are old. I'll try your first approach.